Should a source file end with new line or not? What about backslash + newline?
If we don't end a source file with a new line character but just a } after main(), then the clang compiler (in strict mode
-std=c17 -pedantic-errors) infamously complains:
error: no newline at end of file [-Werror,-Wnewline-eof]

So where did they get this from? It would seem taken from C17 5.1.1.2 Translation phases, emphasis mine:

Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is
deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on
any physical source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. A source file that is
not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a
backslash character before any such splicing takes place.

This first describes how the preprocessor merges lines in the presence of a \. If would seem that the intention of this whole translation phase is to decribe line splicing specifically and not source files in general.
There seems to be some confusion about the last sentence. If I end my file with \ (new line) then now clang suddenly lets the code through in direct violation of the above quoted normative part in the standard. gcc however complains about the non-conformance:

error: backslash-newline at end of file

Sure, the translation phases are not part of a constraint so the compiler doesn't have to generate a diagnostic. But why is clang behaving all backwards?
I checked the C99 rationale and it says that the intention of allowing backslash + new line as a general way to splice lines, string literals etc was added as per C89 for maximum portability: "the C89 Committee generalized this mechanism to permit any token to be continued by interposing a backslash/newline sequence". This would be why backslash + new line with no trailing tokens after doesn't make any sense.

Using a backslash and newline is only relebvant inside string literals. The clang compiler is telling you it requires a newline after the final closing brace.

This post answers your first question. So you should edit your post to focus on the second question or it is likely to be closed.

@OldBoy It also works with macros.

The only actual question I see here is "why is clang behaving all backwards?", which I'd be inclined to close as opinion-based.  And although details of the spec are presented and discussed, I don't see how any language-lawyer reasoning is called for in answering that question. I'm guessing, then, that you somehow missed expressing the question you really want answered. I have a guess or two about what that might be, but I'm not confident enough to devote time to writing a language-lawyer answer to those guesses.

@Spencer My question is about C, I don't care about POSIX at all.

@JohnBollinger The main question is if a C file should end with a new line or not and if so where in the C standard does it say so. The translation phase part was the only relevant part I could find. The bonus question is why clang is seemingly non-conforming when it comes to ending a source file with backslash + newline.

From the second answer of the link posted by @Spencer: "The C language standard says A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character. This is in section 2.1.1.2 of the ANSI C 1989 standard. Section 5.1.1.2 of the ISO C 1999 standard (and probably also the ISO C 1990 standard)."

@isrnick In which case the "bonus" question has to be answered: if this sentence (already quoted in the question) is the reason why clang requires newline at the end, then why does clang allow a newline character immediately preceded by a backslash. Whereas for example gcc in conforming mode does not. It is as if clang chose to only read half of that sentence, ignoring the "shall" in normative text but focusing on the newline part.

GCC has relaxed the backslash-newline processing rules to allow spaces after the backslash — see GCC manual — Escaped Newlines.  I don't like that change.


The main question is if a C file should end with a new line or not and if so where in the C standard does it say so. The translation phase part was the only relevant part I could find.

Yes, that's the part that says a source file must end with a (non-escaped) newline. You expressed doubt about the applicability of that requirement based on it being bundled with the specifications for line splicing, but I don't see how that would matter.  The spec requires a non-escaped newline at the end of the file, with the result that the source file overall, if non-empty, must have the form of a sequence of one or more newline-terminated lines (at the end of phase 2, but that requires the same at the beginning of phase 2).
If the spec merely wanted to forbid an escaped newline at the end of a source file then it would have said that, and the relevant language would have been simpler than what it actually does say.  Something like this, for example: "Prior to such line splicing, a non-empty source file shall not end in a new-line character immediately preceded by a backslash character."
I see no reason to interpret the requirement for a non-escaped newline at the end of a source file as meaning anything other than what it says on its face.

The bonus question is why clang is seemingly non-conforming when it comes to ending a source file with backslash + newline

Clang does not, for this reason, fail to conform.  It accepts non-conforming source without emitting a diagnostic, but conforming implementations are permitted to do that as long as the non-conformance does not involve a constraint violation.  I am inclined to guess that this particular omission is contrary to the intent of Clang's authors, such that it constitutes a program flaw, but you would have to ask them.  Possibly by submitting a bug report.
In any case, Clang's behavior is not well characterized as "backwards".  It does diagnose one bona fide source-conformance issue, but fails to diagnose a different, related one.  That may be flawed, but it doesn't seem backwards to me.

The reason I find it "backwards" is simply: why would one ever want to stick a backslash into the source? You do it for one single reason: there is more to follow. And so the diagnostic from gcc makes perfect sense: "hey you have a backslash but no more pp-tokens so you might have a bug here". Whereas clang does not care about that, but insists on a new line character just to (partially) follow the standard. And since they didn't warn for the benefit of the programmer but just because the standard says so, then why not actually follow the very sentence in the standard where it says as much...

@Lundin, I guess it depends on with respect to what you call it "backwards".  I maintain that Clang's behavior is not well described as backwards with respect to the language spec, which I have taken to be the appropriate measure for this language-lawyer question.  I accept that there may be other senses in which that behavior could be considered backwards.  I'm going to stop there, because this detail is a question of English language interpretation and semantics, probably somewhat subjective, and thus off-topic for SO.

One possible point of confusion that you don't address explicitly: a newline at the end of the file does not necessarily mean an empty line at the end of the file. If the file ends with "foo\n", most editors will show a final line of "foo".  An empty line would be displayed if you had "foo\n\n". The key idea is that a "line" is a sequence of non-newline characters followed by one newline character.

You're right, @Ray, I don't address how various text editors display the last bit of conforming C source files.  I don't take that to be part of the question.  With that said, my personal experience of editor behavior is different from what you describe: I don't remember ever working with an editor that did not distinguish between files ending with zero, one, and two line terminators, though I could imagine that being different on a system whose text conventions require a newline on each line, such that a file that doesn't have one is deficient. [...]

[...] but I take that to be the point of C's requirement in the first place: a C source file is to have strict (logical) line termination semantics, consistent with systems (largely extinct?) that require text lines to be terminated.  It is immaterial to C whether such a file is interpreted by text editors as having a trailing blank line or not.

@JohnBollinger Immaterial to C, certainly. But if the text editor always puts a newline at the end of each line, and doesn't make it explicit that it's doing so, it's quite possible for a user to not realize that the newline is there (vim, for instance, alerts the user when there isn't a newline there, but since by default, it'll always add the newline, most users will never see the warning). I used to add a superfluous newline at the end thinking I was just adding the terminating newline, due to this exact misunderstanding, so I worried that the OP might have the same misunderstanding.
